# Syncing files over different accounts buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I’m trying to sync one aws bucket to an another bucket across different iam accounts.
How can I do it periodically so any file written to the source bucket will automatically transforms to the destination? Do I need to use lambdas to execute aws cli sync command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: AWS CLI Sync**

You could run `aws s3 sync` on a regular basis, which will only copy new/changed files. This makes it very efficient. However, if there is a large number of files (10,000+) then it will take a long time trying to determine which files need to be copied. You will also need to schedule the command to run somewhere (eg a `cron` job).

**Option 2: AWS Lambda function**

You could create an **AWS Lambda function** that is triggered by Amazon S3 whenever a new object is created. The Lambda function will be passed details of the Bucket & Object via the `event` parameter. The Lambda function could then call `CopyObject()` to copy the object *immediately*. The advantage of this method is that the objects are copied as soon as they are created.

(Do *not* use an AWS Lambda function to call the AWS CLI. The above function would be called for each file individually.)

**Option 3: Amazon S3 Replication**

You can configure [Amazon S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) to automatically replicate newly-created objects between the buckets (including buckets between different AWS Accounts). This is the simplest option since it does not require any coding.

**Permissions**

When copying S3 objects between accounts, you will need to **use a single set of credentials** that has both Read permission on the source bucket and Write permission on the target bucket. This can be done in two ways:

- Use credentials (IAM User or IAM Role) from the **source account** that have permission to read the source bucket. Create a **bucket policy on the target bucket** that permits those credentials to `PutObject` into the bucket. When copying, specify `ACL=public-read` to grant object ownership to the destination account.

OR

- Use credentials from the **target account** that have permission to write to the target bucket. Create a **bucket policy on the source bucket** that permits those credentials to `GetObject` from the bucket.